# How to set a PHP session variable when click on a button and stay at the same page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have on my webpage a DIV with a button to close it. When I click that button the DIV slides up with jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="closeable">
   <a id="close_button"></a>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#close_button').click (function () {
    $('#closeable').slideUp();
});
```

But I also want at the same time to set in PHP `$_SESSION['variable'] = 'value'` when click on the button. I have read that the only way is to use Ajax, but how to manage it without losing the jQuery's animation slideUp?

Any idea, please? I used Ajax several times, but despite that, I do not know how to do this.

Comment: _without losing the jQuery's animation slideUp_ .. No, you will not loose anything.. try it

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, so you won't lose any animations if you use it. Try it first.

Comment: heres the jquery ajax docu: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ you can call your .slideUp() inside the complete method for example.

Comment: But then, do I have to create a new PHP file with only the line $_SESSION['variable'] = 'value'; and after that call it from the Ajax function (inside the button click code)? What should I write in success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send ajax request after slide up your div.

try like this:

```
$('#close_button').click (function () {
    $('#closeable').slideUp();
    $.ajax({
      url: "your_file.php",
      }).done(function() {
        //do anything
     });
});
```

or you can slideup your div in ajax success call back like this:

```
 $('#close_button').click (function () {

        $.ajax({
          url: "your_file.php",
          }).done(function() {
            $('#closeable').slideUp();
         });
    });
```

in your your_file.php you need to do whatever you wanted to do like this:

```
$_SESSION['variable'] = 'value';
```

Here is the ajax documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Let me know if you have any confusion ?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. I am going to try it. Thank you so much! I let you know the result.

Comment: I managed to set the session variable for you, thank you so much (in the other attempts I did before asking I could not do it). But there is still the other problem, now the DIV disappears without sliding up when I click on the button.

Comment: Oooohhhhh you were totally right, I had a stupid mistake on mi code (# instead of .) Now it slides up OK. Thank you for your patience!!!